# How to take the specifical class for lambda expression, e.g. subclass of the type in method parameters

Tags: lambda, mockito

I'm trying to add a customized `ArgumentMatcher(subclass of Matcher)` for mockito testing, following is the code:

```
when(mockedObject.mockedMethod(
   argThat((int id)-> id > 5 || id < 1 ? false : true)));
```

but I receives the error :

> Multiple non-overriding abstract methods found in interface org.hamcrest.Matcher

I know that the `argThat` is defined as:

```
public static <T> T argThat(Matcher<T> matcher)
```

Can I tell the compiler that I want to use `ArgumentMatcher`, not Matcher in lambda expression?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, what you want is not possible. `org.hamcrest.Matcher` is not a functional interface. It has multiple non-abstract methods. For example any of these:

- `org.hamcrest.SelfDescribing.describeTo(Description)`
- `org.hamcrest.Matcher.matches(Object)`

The compiler needs to convert a lambda to an implementation of a functional interface. But `ArgumentMatcher` itself is already a class.

As a workaround you could create your own version of `argThat` that receives a `java.util.function.Predicate` and converts that to a `Matcher` implementation. However you will loose the support of `SelfDescribing` and have to live with bad failure descriptions.